# How to write a proxy server in Python?

Tags: python, proxy, http-headers

I want to write a program that changes the HTTP headers in my requests that are sent by my web-browser. I believe it can be done with a proxy server. So, I'd like to write a proxy server.

I study programming. How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 14):

Good example below on how to do this without the overhead of a framework.

http://www.warriorhut.org/whatwg/websocket-proxy.py

Answer (score 13):

Look at the [Twisted framework](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedProject), particularly [Twisted Web](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWeb).  It's all freely available under MIT, so you can build off and/or modify it.

See also [Python Twisted Examples](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Twisted-Examples).

Answer (score 7):

While Twisted, as recommended by @Matthew, is awesome, easier to learn, understand and modify might be [this tiny example](http://www.oki-osk.jp/esc/python/proxy/) -- far away from the "production quality" and scalability that Twisted can offer, but, you could start with it to understand the issues better.

For a *wide* variety of open-source HTTP proxies written in Python, I recommend [this list](http://proxies.xhaus.com/) -- **that** reference has proxies for all tastes built on top of threading, Twisted, asyncore, and other technologies yet!

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at Tiny HTTP Proxy (1) and of course the related docs (2). It's basically running a server and handling requests.

(1) http://www.oki-osk.jp/esc/python/proxy/
(2) http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html

Comment: Updated link: http://www.oki-osk.jp/esc/python/proxy/

Answer (score 3):

WSGI may be a little easier to get your head around. So I'll throw paste.proxy out there either as something to build on or as a reference.

http://pythonpaste.org/modules/proxy.html

Answer (score 2):

http://twistedmatrix.com/

Great library for any networking needs.